# How to share an url and a title along with google share?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I want to share an url and a title along with google share like Facebook

[https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[URL]&t=[TEXT]](https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%5bURL%5d&t=%5bTEXT%5d)

For example: $title = "Title";

$url = "example.com";

In this url https://plus.google.com/share?url=url, have pass only the url. How to pass a title with this url by dynamically?

Thanks,

Parthiban

Comment: The content of the share is calculated by Google+ on the page based on a mix of schema, open graph, or the page content. There are a number of answers that should cover what you need to know and the docs are at https://developers.google.com/+/web/share